# My string.replace does not work in my python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Code:

```py
a = input("Enter your DNA sequence: ")
a = a.upper()
print("Your DNA sequence is", a)
str(a)
RNA = a.replace('C', 'G')
RNA = a.replace('A', "U")
RNA = a.replace('T', 'A')
print(RNA)
```

What's wrong with my code? I'm sure this should be working, I am even re-assigning `RNA` to the `.replace()`

Comment: you're using `a` instead of `RNA`, so effectively you don't save the changes even though you think you are. change to `RNA = RNA.replace('A', "U")` and so on

Comment: you are  re-assigning "RNA" every time but you are replacing only "a" variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing the changes in multiple steps always refer the updated result. In your case, you need to use `RNA.replace` from the second update as shown below.

```
a = input("Enter your DNA sequence: ")
a = a.upper()
print("Your DNA sequence is", a)
##a=str(a)
RNA = a.replace('C', 'G')
RNA = RNA.replace('A', "U")
RNA = RNA.replace('T', 'A')
print("RNA is :",RNA)
```

And the output for this is as desired.

```
Enter your DNA sequence: CATAEQ
Your DNA sequence is CATAEQ
RNA is : GUAUEQ
```